# Why I cannot disable some dates in datetimepicker based on my logic in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm using the following javascript: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker , and I want to achieve simple effect - when User selects today's day, it should show him only hours available from now until the end of the day, the previous time should be disabled. But when he choses any other day in the future - then the whole time should be available. And one more thing - I want to use the american timezone all the time, so I get it from the server by php. Later on I'm using moment.js to parse it and then I'm including it in datetimepicker. I wrote the following function in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    var today;
    var time = 1443571620;
    var newyorktime = time - 5*60*60;
        today = new Date(newyorktime*1000);
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth();
        var yy = today.getFullYear();
        var hh = today.getHours();

        var now = new Date(newyorktime*1000);
        now.setHours(now.getHours());

        var isPM = now.getHours() >= 12;
        var isMidday = now.getHours() == 12;
        var result = document.querySelector('#result');
        var time = [now.getHours() - (isPM && !isMidday ? 12 : 0),
            now.getMinutes()].join(':') +
                (isPM ? ' pm' : 'am');
        alert(now);

        var logic = function (currentDateTime) {
            var currentDateTimestamp = moment(currentDateTime).unix()-5*60*60;
            currentDateTime = new Date(currentDateTimestamp*1000);
            if (currentDateTime.getDate() == dd && currentDateTime.getFullYear() == yy && ((currentDateTime.getMonth()) == mm)) {
    alert(now); 
                this.setOptions({
                    formatTime: 'g:i A',
                    format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
                    minDate: '1970/01/02', //or 1986/12/08,
                    minTime: time
                });
            } else
                this.setOptions({
                    formatTime: 'g:i A',
                    format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
                    minDate: '+1970/01/02', //or 1986/12/08,
                    minTime: '0:00 AM'
                });
        };

        $('#datetimepicker').val(dd+"/"+(mm+1)+"/"+yy+" "+time);
        jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            onChangeDateTime: logic,
            onShow: logic
        });


}
);
```

Currently it doesn't work well enough - even when we enter the `if (currentDateTime.getDate() == dd && currentDateTime.getFullYear() == yy && ((currentDateTime.getMonth()) == mm)) {` if statement - I'm not able to block the previous hours somehow. How can I do that?

In general - let's say it's 30th of September, 11am. When the user clicks the datetimepicker, he should see available all dates/times starting from 30th of September 11am (previous dates/hours should be greyed out). But when he chooses some next days - then all hours should be enabled and he should have a possibility of choosing them. Currently it doesn't work.
Please help..

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b8o5cvdz/8/

Comment: What do you mean by all hours? When user choose october 1, previous day should be available?

Comment: in my example when user clicks 1st of October he should have possibility of choosing time from 0AM to 11:59PM, when he chooses 30th of september than he should have possibilities of choosing time only from 11AM to 11:59PM